# Generalizing the formula for $\Lambda_k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

Let $\Lambda_k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{n!}$. I was practicing evaluating exponential series, and I encountered the following few series $\Lambda_2=2e, \Lambda_3=5e$ and $\Lambda_4=15e$ which can be proven by using the taylor series expression for $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n/n!$. But doing this all over may prove challenging in an exam situation. So I tried generalizing the formula for the exponent of $n$ as $k$.

**My Attempt**:

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^k}{n!}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^{k-1}-1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\\ &=\left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}n^i}{(n-2)!}\right)\right)+e \end{aligned}$$

I'm not sure how to proceed next. A hint in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula

Comment: Thanks @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to proceed is to note that for each $j$, if we define
$$\phi_j(n)=n(n-1)\cdots(n-j+1)$$
(that is $\phi_j(n)=j!\binom nj$) then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\phi_j(n)}{n!}=\sum_{n=j}^\infty\frac1{(n-j)!}=e.$$
For example,
$$n^4=\phi_4(n)+6\phi_3(n)+7\phi_2(n)+\phi_1(n)$$
and so
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^4}{n!}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\phi_4(n)+6\phi_3(n)+7\phi_2(n)+\phi_1(n)}{n!}
=(1+6+7+1)e=15e.$$
In general then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{n!}
=e\sum_{j=0}^k a_{k,j}$$
where
$$n^k=\sum_{j=0}^ka_{k,j}\phi_j(n).$$
Now, there is a combinatorial interpretation for these "connecting coefficients"
$a_{k,j}$.